# Create a DB via SSH that will appear in CPanel

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, mysql5

I have a linux VPS. I want to be able to create a database via SSH and still have access to it via CPanel. I tried creating a database using `create database myDB` and it did create it and I can see it when I use `show databases;` but I cannot see it when I log in to my control panel as `myUser`. I did try granting permissions to `myUser` on that database but it didn't seem to help (unless I did it wrong).

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Using CentOS and MySQL5.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue: Turns out in the source is doesn't show any databases in phpMyAdmin with a name that contains `test`. Just my luck to call mine autotest :)

Ref: http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=19698